# How to simulate typing in input to make angular filter work

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, input, filter

For example I have list of countries `<div class="container" ng-init="
    countries=['Ukraine','Urugvai','Russia','Romania','Rome','Argentina','Britain']
    ">` and I'm showing them via ng-repeat:

```
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="country in countries | filter:q">{{ country }}</li>
  </ul>
```

Then I made input for filtering:

```
<input id="q" type="text" ng-model="q"/>
```

Also, I have alphabet list:

```
<ul>
  <li class="letter">A</li>
  <li class="letter">B</li>
  <li class="letter">R</li>
  <li class="letter">U</li>
</ul>
```

What i'm tring to do, is to get letter when I click on `.letter` and put this letter to input to start filtering my countries list:

```
$(document).on('click','.letter',function(){
  var el = $(this);
  var html = el.html();
  var firstLetter = html.charAt(0);
  $('#q').val(firstLetter);
});
```

So when I click on letter it takes this letter and puts into input field. But then nothing happened... Clicked letter shows up in input field, but filter doesn't work.

So my question is, how to make this works? How to simulete typing in input field when I put there letter?

Thanx a lot in advance!

P.S. Here is my [Plunker DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/KDaNT85Z6ODoolw98XzI?p=preview)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Explanation and solution #1 (bad)**

Nothing happens because you never told Angular that model has changes. You are using plaing Javascript outside of Angular "world". In this case you need to update scope manually and trigger digest loop:

```
$(document).on('click', '.letter', function() {
    var el = $(this);
    var html = el.html();
    var x = 'some';
    var firstLetter = html.charAt(0);
    //alert(firstLetter);
    $('#q').val(firstLetter);


    var scope = angular.element($('#q')[0]).scope();
    scope.q = firstLetter;
    scope.$apply();
});
```

**Warning:** But this is **not** how you should do it, **avoid** doing this by all means.

**Solution #2 (better)**

Instead use `ngClick` directive to update `q` model and your code will become mush cleaner.

In HTML you will put ngClick directives:

```
<ul>
    <li class="letter" ng-click="setTerm('A')">A</li>
    <li class="letter" ng-click="setTerm('B')">B</li>
    <li class="letter" ng-click="setTerm('R')">R</li>
    <li class="letter" ng-click="setTerm('U')">U</li>
</ul>
```

and in controller:

```
app.controller('MainController', function($scope) {
    $scope.setTerm = function(letter) {
        $scope.q = letter;
    };
});
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/N0DpH9kNTndo498eempF?p=preview

However, even this this looks closer to Angular-style solution, it's still not ideal due to the fact that you need to duplicated ngClick handlers on every LI element. Here we come to the probably best solution for this problem - custom directive, one of the key ideas of Angular.

**Solution #3 (best)**

You can create custom directive to avoid writing the same ngClick handler for every list item. Not only it's too verbose, but also less efficient because every ngClick binds new click event.

Simple directive could look something like this:

```
app.directive('searchList', function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            searchModel: '=model'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.on('click', attrs.searchList, function() {
                scope.searchModel = $(this).text();
                scope.$apply();
            });
        }
    };
});
```

and be used this way:

```
<ul search-list=".letter" model="q">
    <li class="letter">A</li>
    <li class="letter">B</li>
    <li class="letter">R</li>
    <li class="letter">U</li>
</ul>
```

This is very flexible (can be used with different models and reused, can be used with limited set of items within list (CSS selector)) and efficient solution (only one event handler).

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/rZrPheCy6FToWsPRLgAV

Comment: Wow!...i have no words to express my fillings...
Thank You, sir, for such wide and popular explanation!

Comment: I have one question to You, sir: does it better to make separate controller for Countries and change ng-init on ng-controller="CountriesController"?
[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/nrS2zNCXJwAznMiX50p2?p=preview)

What solution 1st (with ng-init="countires=[ '...','...','...' ]") or 2nd(with ng-contoller="CountiresContoller") will be better and easier for backender to fill with counties names?

In 1st solution DOM will be visible (<div class="container" ng-init="countries=['Ukraine','Urugvai','Russia','Romania','Rome','Argentina','Britain']">)... Second seems to be better and cleaner...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Reactive Forms, try `FormControl.updateValueAndValidity()`